# Transfer ONLY email accounts from one server to another

Tags: ssh, centos, webserver

Okay. So the company I work with just transferred web servers. I have SSH access to both machines. Without making a FULL cpanel backup, is there a way I can transfer JUST the email accounts from the old to the new? SSH SCP?

Comment: Do you know the passwords for the accounts, in other words, can you create the accounts so that only the emails and folders need transferring?

Comment: No, though I could hypothetically change them to get to that point.

Comment: If they are IMAP you might be able to use Imapsync. I think you might have to know the password though, which might be a bummer for your situation. It's been a while since I've used it; so I forget exactly.  http://imapsync.lamiral.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folders and emails are stored in ~/mail and is a standard Maildir format.  So if you can recreated the accounts on the new server, you should be able to copy everything over with scp as you suggested:

```
scp user@remoteserver:/home/user/mail/* /home/user/mail/ -r
```

Then copy/paste the appropriate lines in /etc/passwd /etc/group and /etc/shadow to duplicate the accounts.

Make sure the UID and GID of the copied mails match the new server settings.